# Obvious spam declined from being flagged?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation

I was just reviewing my "helpful flags", and [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27416514/is-anybody-interested-in-mathematica-related-programming-with-delphi) (deleted now) I had flagged as spam. Just by looking at the title, it's obviously spam:

> Is anybody interested in Mathematica related programming with Delphi?

However, it appears a moderator has reviewed it and concluded it is not spam...

[image: spam flag declined]

I've seen other people asking similar questions here on MSO, but there's a legitimate reason for each one. But I don't see what's legitimate about declining this flag. I could understand a reason such as being in another language where the moderator didn't translate it to see that it was spam. Or if the content wasn't spam but somewhat spamish. But the question I flagged was someone trying to recruit someone to work for them (at least that's what I remember, I can't see the content to say for sure).

From what I understand, a moderator who has the power to approve/reject flags should also have the power to see deleted questions. So "the question was deleted" is not a valid excuse.

Why would a moderator review this question and then decide that it is not spam?

**EDIT** added by higher-rep user:

Here is the body for <10K users:

> Is anybody interested in Mathematica related programming with Delphi?
>   I have done a bit of code porting, any suggestions on pascal style
>   porting are welcomed.

Comment: While a terrible question, that's borderline to me for spam. I wouldn't *necessarily* read it as soliciting someone to work for them (at least at the current revision, no edit history shown). Given the harsh spam penalty, I could see a decline.

Comment: The second sentence seems to suggest that they were looking for off-site resources, not trying to hire someone. I probably wouldn't have looked at it as spam either.

Comment: I don't have sufficient privileges to see the content, so it's difficult for me to know.

Comment: This was hardly spam.

Comment: I see, now that I can see the rest of the content.

Comment: The moderators will answer this completely, but there are certain penalties that come along with an answer that is marked as "spam" - above and beyond the other flagging/closing reasons. So unless it is definitely spam, they won't mark it as spam. The post you flagged doesn't look like spam, just a very, very poor question.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I don't even see what is borderline about it.  It is a crap question but is clearly not spam in the way Stack Exchange defines it

Comment: Without being able to see the content of the question, and being some time since it happened, I had no idea how to identify it at this time. Just the title alone appears as spam, but with the content, I can see how it is not spam. Sure, many of you can see the content, and someone even added this content to my question after I asked it. But before-hand, I could not see this, at the time I asked this question. Only the title.

Comment: @JerryDodge I don't see how you could interpret the title as being spam. A poorly phrased title in an attempt to solicit input of enthusiasts: yes, advertisement: not even close

Comment: I misread it as "Is anybody interested in Mathematica related programming **in Delhi**?", in which case, it almost certainly would be spam!

Comment: @Nathan: Except Jerry has plenty of experience in the **delphi** tag, so he didn't make that same mistake.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to keep in mind the definition of "spam" (at least for StackOverflow's purposes), which is shown to you when you go to flag:

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

Here's another quote from [this StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/276203) that adds more information on what constitutes spam:

> **What makes something spam and when should I flag it?**
>
> A post should be marked as spam ONLY when it contains an unsolicited
> advertisement.
>
> It should NOT be marked as spam when:
>
> The answer contains no useful information, such as an answer that says
> "I don't care about your problem". Flag an answer as 'not an answer'
> instead; if you find a weird non-question, then flag it 'for moderator
> attention' with a custom explanation.
>
> It contains gibberish, such as "fsdguejgkfdlk". Again, flag an answer
> as 'not an answer', or flag a question 'for moderator attention' with
> a custom explanation.

Looking at the quote provided, I'm not seeing any sort of advertisement. I'm not seeing any sort of promotion. I'm seeing something that has a *lot* of problems and certainly isn't a good question for the site, but **is still a question**.

Now, you may say that the question is very low quality, opinion-based, looking for off-site resources, and off-topic - and you'd be right. So why doesn't the mod just close the question anyway? Well, there are certain penalties that come with a post being deleted as spam by a moderator for the account which posted it that go above and beyond the regular penalties for deleted posts. For this reason, moderators likely won't delete a question marked as spam, *even if it's low quality and could be deleted for other reasons*.

You can find a list of some of the effects from the [same post I linked above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/276203):

> The spam flag is designed to eliminate posts with no relevant content and to penalize the authors:
>
> - 3 flags (spam or offensive): post is banished from the front page.
> - 6 flags (spam or offensive): post is [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post), deleted, and the first revision owner loses 100 reputation.
> - 1 flag from a moderator has the same effect as 6 flags from normal users: instant destruction.
> - Because a question with 6 flags is locked and deleted by the Community user, a 10k reputation user cannot undelete it.
> - Each flag carries an implicit downvote for calculating the post's score *(it does not affect the caster's reputation)*.

Comment: Yeah, basically this. A question can be complete garbage, but still not be spam. Spam flags feed into a spam detection system, so we tend to be pretty strict on those flags.

Comment: "Looking at the quote you provided" - just to be clear, I didn't provide that. Someone who had privileges to see it edited my question to provide it. At the time I asked this question, I could only see the title, which does appear as spam.

Comment: @JerryDodge You have to be very careful with that then. I've seen posts with terrible titles that have turned out to be OK questions. Sometimes the OP is posting for the first time and just needs some help figuring out what to title the question. You also probably shouldn't flag a post if you aren't sure/if you can only see the title.