# First post review audit deceptive because a copy-pasted answer ought to be flagged

Tags: support, review-audits

I just got into an audit that showed me a high quality post:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/6756487

But the answer I saw looked exactly like the answer that was already there, only with another username that had 1 reputation.

So I thought *"This must be some kind of spam"* and flagged it accordingly.

Then I got warned, that it actually was that very same high quality post, but with a fake new username.

This doesn't work like this! If you want to test me, you shouldn't create fake usernames. I think I did the right thing by flagging an **exact copied duplicate** as spam, didn't I?

Comment: Then why didn't you see the post from review **and** the post it was mastered from in the question? You didn't? In that case, it's obviously a review and you should vote as if they are one-and-the-same, because they are. So, "looks good". Well, at least you seem to pay attention, next time you'll know sometimes a post under review will be cloaked, and still vote on the merits of the post you see, not on the fact that it's actually not what it seems.

Comment: Clue: Did you see *two* answers on the actual post that were exactly the same?

Comment: No there was only one answer, so my conclusion was that it was spam and already deleted (there are often working two reviewers at the same post)

Comment: what do you mean? what is not useful? Are you creating those autits?

Comment: I meant my hint to check if there actually is a duplicate answer isn't as helpful when you can't see deleted answers (like 10K+ users can)

Comment: If a (first) post is indeed a copy-paste duplicate of an existing answer, @Deduplicator, that's a legitimate problem -- it should _not_ be marked "No action needed".

Comment: I think it is a bad trap, that can be misunderstood, because it just looks really strange, and no reviewer will do the right thing here (which supposed to be to **upvote** this messed up duplicate) You should remove this test, cause it is not fair and anyway this can never happen in real live when you are reviewing posts

Comment: I actually agree with you, its confusing if you are trying to get context by looking at the actual post. There's a reason the posts are anonymized though, because if you saw a "First Post" by a 50K user, it would be too obvious that its an audit.

Comment: It is just pointless to use a +50K users post as a "First Post" to test us ;|

Comment: @Deduplicator, that wasn't quite how I read your comment, no, but I think that you are misinterpreting this Meta post. The point here seems to be that it isn't clear from the review interface that the reviewed post is a _copy_, rather than being a separate answer that isn't shown in the question view _for some unknown reason_. If it were indeed a separate answer -- which is not completely implausible -- then action should be taken on it.

Comment: *spam* has a very strict definition here, and a plagiarized answer (a copy/paste of another answer) does not meet that definition. The spam flag should be used sparingly and only for posts that meet the definition, because it has serious repercussions (loss of 100 reputation points, possible suspension or banning of the user's account, and even an IP block). If you're not 100% sure the post meets this site's definition of spam, don't use the flag.

Comment: *It is just pointless to use a +50K users post as a "First Post" to test us* - No, apparently it is *not* pointless, because you failed the test. :-)

Comment: Just as more information, the definition of *spam* here is explained very clearly in [What are the spam and offensive flags, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/172661)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, maybe part of the issue is learning to get along with the audit system. The audits have a very specific set of rules - they do things the same way every time (as they are automated). Maybe it isn't the ideal system, but it serves its purpose pretty well. Of course the username and reputation will be hidden in the "first post" queue - if you could see that the user who posted the answer has nearly 20k reputation, you would of course realize that it's an audit because *it obviously wouldn't be the user's first post*. Likewise, of course the system hides the votes, because then you would be able to judge the post by the number of votes and not its content.

Second of all, and more importantly, you should be going by **what's presented to you** - which in this case, is a fairly high quality answer by a user who appeared to you to have 1 reputation. You got yourself in trouble when you opened the question in a new window and saw that same post with high votes. People more experienced with audits know that this is the way the audit system works, and that is the same post. If that's going to confuse you, then don't even open the question in a new page. Judge what you're presented.

I think that in the end, you overthought this a little bit. Yeah, it's possible that somehow a user posted a carbon copy of another answer, that was very heavily downvoted and flagged, subsequently deleted, and then chosen to be an audit because of all of the negative actions taken on it. But not very likely. **If you had followed the process that was intended, and reviewed exactly what you had been presented, you would have been fine.**

Let me add as an afterthought the gist of some of the comments as well. I'm not sure what you mean by "flagged it accordingly," but you seem to imply that you flagged that answer as spam. Take a look at [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283335/4015623) to get a bit more info on what constitutes spam and what doesn't. This post certainly is not spam by StackOverflow's definition.

Comment: Ok. So Next time: if i would really encounter a plagiarised answer, what would be a correct handling?

Comment: If you encounter it outside of the review queue, flag it for moderator attention and explain the situation/provide the mod with a link to the original answer. If you're in the review queue, go by the quality of the answer

Comment: I would note that this doesn't always work properly, since sometimes audits can and will be generated from precisely the opposite case: seemingly-good answers that *are* plagiarized and *were* flagged and deleted accordingly. The only universal solution is to not merely open in a new tab, but to check the position the page loads to: the top of the window will be scrolled to the top of the post you're actually reviewing, unless it's a deleted answer, in which case the question will be shown instead.